# Unable to display interface value of array type

Tags: json, typescript, angular6

I have an component called `demo`, In which i am displaying some data from **API**.

html

```
   <div  *ngFor="let  user of users">
      <p>Name: {{user?.name}}</p
      <p>Phone: {{user?.addresses}}</p
   </div>
```

ts

```
import { Component,  Input } from '@angular/core';
import {  User} from '../app-models';

@Component({
 selector: 'wsd-demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.css'],
})

export class DemoComponent  {
 @Input()
 public users: User;
}
```

app-models.ts (declared interface (User) in this file)

```
 export interface User{
    name: string;
    addresses:  IAddressElement[];
 }

 export interface IAddressElement {
     type:            string;
     city:            string;
     countryOrRegion: string;
     postalCode:      string;
     state:           string;
   }
```

Json

```
  "name": "Jhon",
   "addresses": [
    {
        "address": {
            "type": "Home",
            "city": "Loretto",
            "countryOrRegion": "United States",
            "postalCode": "00000",
            "state": "Minnesota",
        }
      },
      {
        "address": {
            "type": "Business",
            "city": "Norwalk",
            "countryOrRegion": "United States",
            "postalCode": "1111",
            "state": "Connecticut",
        }
      },
      {
        "address": {
            "type": "Business",
            "city": "Huntington",
            "countryOrRegion": "United States",
            "postalCode": "33333",
            "state": "West Virginia",
        }
     }
   ],
```

I am facing an issue. In the html the `name` is displaying fine. But while displaying address(i,e addresses).
It is displaying as

> **[object Object] [object Object]**.

I want display all the address, I tried using ***ngFor** but didn't got exact result..:)

Comment: json is invalid

Comment: How it is invalid??

Comment: user.addresses==> is array that's why you got [object] and there is no phone in your json ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the addresses array as it is. You have to loop through them and print what you need. I'm not an Angular guy though.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <p>Name: {{user?.name}}</p>
  <div *ngFor="let a of user?.addresses">
    <p>State: {{a.address.state}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```